# Is it permissible for a man to wear clothing that may attract women?

Tags: halal-haram, clothing

If a man thinks that his clothing may attract women non-mahram to him, is it necessary for him to wear a different clothing?

Comment: By women, do you mean his wife or the non-mehram?

Comment: @Ahmed I mean the non-mahram women

Comment: Does [Qur'an 24:30](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=24&verse=30) answer your question?

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser No, I want to know about clothing for men. Is there any such restriction as mentioned in the question for men?